# Aiogram проверка поллинга

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, aiogram

В коде есть три потока. Один за gui, второй за бот, третий за контроль. Надо сделать, чтобы третий поток узнавал состояние, запущен ли поллинг. Это надо в первую очередь чтобы после нажатия "Старт" был ползунок запуска и исчезал после запуска поллинга. Каким образом проверять, идёт ли поллинг?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вводных данных мало. На StackOverflow принято приходить с конкретикой. О каком "Старт" вы говорите - не понятно.
2. Способов передать информацию есть множество:

- взять объект диспетчера и проверить состояние
- передавать состояние во внешний сервис
- можете даже из под своего пользователя автоматизировать отправку и получение сообщения

Перечислять п.2 можно бесконечно.
Проблема кроется в странной архитектуре описанного выше приложения.